# python - JSON file from sql query

Tags: python, json, pivot

I have a table as following:

```
Name,Shoes

John,Nike
John,Adidas
John,Brand3
David,Nike
David,Adidas
Simon,Nike
Simon,Adidas
Simon,Brand3
Simon,Brand4
```

How can I create a JSON file like that:

```
{"John":"nike,Adidas,Brand3","David":"Nike,Adidas","Simon":"Nike,Adidas,Brand3,Brand4"}
```

In python?

Thanks

Comment: Use `defaultdict(list)`

Answer (score 0):

Python has a collections library from which you can make use of `defaultdict`. Ref https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

If your data is read into a list of format

```
[{"John", "Nike"}, {"John", "Adidas"}, ... , {"Simon", "Brand4"}]
```

You can use defaultdict. It would return the following

```
[('John', ["Nike", "Adidas", ...]), ("Simon", ["Nike", "Adidas", "Brand4"])]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: my last code is:
  AllRows = cur.fetchall()
    print(f'Creating JSON file name: {FileName}.csv')
    jsonData = json.dumps(AllRows)

How can I use it?

Comment: output = defaultdict(jsonData)
TypeError: first argument must be callable or None